# How can one add password to ECC private key generated by openssl?

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve

I am trying to create Elliptic Curve based certificates using the OpenSSL command line interface. I am generating the key files by typing the following command in my CLI:

```sh
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out rootpem.pem
```

The problem is although the ECC key is successfully generated, it is not encrypted with any symmetric cryptography. However, it was pretty simple to encrypt an RSA key using the command below:

```sh
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out 1.key 2048
```

Is there anyway to encrypt ECC keys just like RSA keys?

I have tried "OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016" and "OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017" OpenSSL versions with multiple argument combination but I always get error.

Comment: PS: reading [this wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations), I am sure it's possible to encrypt it. I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I tried, there is not a single line solution for it. It can be generate by piping `openssl ecparam` to `openssl ec` command. One possible solution is this:

```sh
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 | openssl ec -aes-256-cbc -out rootpem.[pem/key]
```

Looking at the generated files, they have similar headers as [the OpenSSL wiki examples](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations). However, I am not sure whether this piping is safe or not as the unencrypted key is nakedly piped.

Answer (score 7):

It is recommended to use the `genpkey` command. It can also generate private keys on the Ed25519 curve and encrypt it with AES-256 in one command:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -aes256 -pass stdin -out private/ca.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it in two steps: first the 'ecparam', then the key

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -out ecparam.pem
openssl genpkey -paramfile ecparam.pem -out key.pem -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:HereIsThePassword
```